# How to stop pushing the heartbeat to the eureka server by client temporarily

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I have a requirement to avoid incoming requests to a one of instance from the instance cluster for some time. Just think the service instance is going to execute a heavy batch process. While doing that batch process, i want to stop sending heartbeat to the eureka service temporarily. After doing that task the instance should be released as a normal active instance to be received the incoming requests.